# When using Cheerio/jQuery, how do I get text from all classes with same name?

Tags: jquery, cheerio

I'm trying to put each 'poetry' class's text into an array, however, the text ends up being an empty string. Does the each() function not work this way on classes?

```
(err, res, body) => {

    if (err) return console.error(err);

    let $ = cheerio.load(body);

    let readings = [];

    $('.poetry').each((i, e)=>{
        readings[i] = $(this).text();
    });
    console.log(readings);
    console.log($('.poetry').text());
})
```

The second console log prints a single string with the text of all of the poetry classes as expected, but I would like to split it up.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Arrow functions do not change the context of `this`.  You need to use `$(e)` instead

Comment: Also rather than using `each()` you should look at the api for `map()`

Comment: Thank you.  The first comment fixed my problem.  I will also check out map().

Comment: Another option is `const readings = [...$('.poetry')].map(e => $(e).text());`